# Error running NPM http-server with unspecified $PORT

Tags: node.js, npm, localhost, port, package.json

In an NPM package.json, the following line should start a local server:

```
...
"start": "npx http-server .out -p $PORT",
...
```

I get an error with what I think says $PORT can't create or find the port it should use for my local server:

```
The value "{ port: true, host: '0.0.0.0' }" is invalid for option "options"
```

When I run the NPM start command to define the port in for the server (or do the same by defining the port manually in package.json) the local server runs just fine:

```
PORT=3000 npm run start
```

**Why won't $PORT by itself in package.json recognize a port to use and start the server? How can I fix this on my local machine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$PORT` is an environment variable. The reason it doesn't work if you don't set it is because that's the way the code is written. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

You can assign a default value by changing the start entry:

```json
"start": "npx http-server .out -p ${PORT:-0}",
```

I gave a default of `0` but you can use whatever you want. `0` seems to be ignored by `http-server` which then uses its own default of `8080`. (In Node.js core, `0` often means "give me an available port, I don't care which one", but not so here.)

If you are trying to solve this for yourself only and do not want to modify `package.json`, you can set `$PATH` in a shell rc file. The file name and how to do it will vary a bit by shell, but a typical one might be `bash`, in which case the start file might be `~/.bashrc` and you'd add a line like `export PORT=3000`. You'll need to open a new shell or run the `.bashrc` (again, varies by shell, might be `source ~/.bashrc` or might be `. ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Thank you @Trott, that worked. I use zsh, so I opened the .zshrc file and added `export PORT=8080`, restarted zsh, and my local server works now.